# why javafx doesn't have infinite loop?

Tags: java, javafx

In some library like GTk or OpenGl we have an Infinite loop like this

```
gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
//our code 
gtk_main();
```

but i didn't see something like this in javafx it is only have a start() method that write our code and launch() method to show stage in start.Can some One explain me about javafx that how does it work and it uses GPU or CPU or Both?
thanks

Comment: I don't know enough about GTK to answer this, but see if [this article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-architecture.htm#JFXST788) helps.

Comment: I've answered your main question before. As for the CPU/GPU, both will be used where available, but it can fall back to a pure software renderer.

Comment: it means that if we have a simple app jfx use CPU but if it has more graphical interface like more models and animations it automatically use GPU ?(assume that jfx know that our system has for example Nvidia)

Comment: As far as I know, whenever it can use the GPU it will do. Even if the app is simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `start()` method of JavaFX creates another thread for the UI to run on. Your main thread (the one that ran `static void main(String[])`) will usually finish after this method call.

The JVM will run until there no threads running anymore. There is an exception to this in daemon threads, but ignore those for now.

The JavaFX thread will do the infinite loop, freeing the programmers from implementing this logic themselves.